# Is there a way to publish my screen (using VNC or similar technology)

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I'm trying to figure out a way to publish my screen using VNC or a similar technology. My intention is to connect a remote PC to a projector/display and connect to that PC so that i can share my screen and have it displayed on the projector.

Ultimately, the solution should support audio as well.

I'm using VNC the 'other way' daily, meaning that i connect to servers and view their screens. However, I'm uncertain as to wether it would be possible to 'reverse' things and publish my screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are expensive projectors that have a NIC built-in, and can do exactly what you're talking about natively. Alternatively there are hardware bridges for such a thing, search "vga over IP" or "hdmi over IP" and you should find them. FWIW I've had good experiences with StarTech

Answer (score 0):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) has the capability to create a video stream of a system's desktop and send it to other systems on a network.